# Spring JPA - One to Many - Re-parenting

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I have some entities in a `one-to-many` relationship.

The parent:

```
@Entity
@Cacheable(false)
@Table(name="form_area")
public class FormArea {

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="formArea", cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST }) 
  private List<AssignableArea> assignableAreas = new ArrayList<AssignableArea>();

  ...
}
```

The child:

```
@Entity
@Cacheable(false)
@Table(name="assignable_area")
public class AssignableArea {
  private @ManyToOne FormArea formArea;
  ...
}
```

The child object, AssignableArea also has getter/setter on the parent, FormArea.

When I re-parent using `setFormArea()`, it seems successful, in that the database contains the correct information. But when I call `getAssignableAreas()` on FormArea:

```
public List<AssignableArea> getAssignableAreas() {
  return Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>(assignableAreas));
}
```

I see the old list, before re-parenting.
Why do I see the old, stale list, when I expect to see the updated list?

Comment: You didn't post the code, so we can only guess. But the most probable reasn is that you've already loaded the FormArea and its list of assignebleAreas, and you only updated one side of the association, so the other side stays as it was loaded: it's your responsibility to maintain both sides of the association if it matters to you. If you start a new transaction and reload the FormArea, its list will contain the correct elements.

Comment: CascadeType.REFRESH ?

Comment: @JBNizet me needing to maintain both sides of the relationship was the key here. Feel free to post it an an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most probable reason is that you've already loaded the `FormArea` and its list of `assignableAreas`, and you only updated one side of the association, so the other side stays as it was loaded: it's your responsibility to maintain both sides of the association if it matters to you.

If you start a new transaction and reload the FormArea, its list will contain the correct elements.